# How To Automate Online Workflow?

Tags: automation, webautomation

I've tried to research this topic and found resources like selenium, but I'm not entirely sure how to do what I need.

Basically here is the workflow:

1. A user completes a form on our website
2. The form inputs get emailed to me
3. I login to the related database system online (it's always the same) to produce the necessary report based on there request.
4. I then print a PDF version of the report and email it back to them with our email template (customized based on some of their inputs on the website)

Is there a way to automate this? Maybe even run it on a server so users can get the reports even when my computer is off?

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you are not able to use API of the resource which gives you PDF file...*

I'd go like this:

1. Configure Jenkins CI on a server.
2. When a user completes a form - send HTTP POST request to Jenkins CI for building parametrized job (using data from user).
3. Jenkins job runs the Selenium tests to get desired PDF file.
4. Using Jenkins email notification plugin send customized email with PDF file from previous step.

Comment: This is great! Thanks I'll take a look.